# FFMPEG: Convert input rec709 to sRGB

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to use ffmpeg to convert an image-sequence of **tiff 16bit rec709** to an image-sequence of **JPEG sRGB**.

```
# How would I indicate ffmpeg source is rec709 and output is srgb?
ffmpeg -start_number 1001 -i input_seq_rec709.%04d.tif output_seq_srgb.%04d.jpg
```

From ffmpeg docs, I can see the conversion options (`colorspace` and `colormatrix`). From what I gather rec709 is like bt709. but I'm not sure what sRGB would be, any idea?
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorspace

I was hoping to use one of these flags, but srgb is not a valid option for FFMPEG.

- `-vf "scale=in_color_matrix=bt709:out_color_matrix=srgb"`
- `-colormatrix=bt709:srgb'`

Thank you

Comment: Just to comment briefly, "Rec709" and "bt709" are the same thing. Also, sRGB is the same as Rec709 EXCEPT for the transfer curve (gamma) which is important. That is, sRGB and Rec709 use identical color primaries and whitepoint, but the encoding curve (i.e. lightness) is a bit different. You can convert Rec709 data to sRGB by applying an exponent of 1.1 to each color channel (R^1.1 G^1.1 B^1.1)

Comment: srgb is not a color matrix. It is a transfer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not positive if this will actually be useful for you, but my messing around with ffmpeg turned up the following flag to indicate sRGB gamma. This is for the H.264 TRC flag "-color_trc iec61966_2_1".

Comment: This will just tag the output not convert anything.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Apart from converting TIF to JPG, which ffmpeg already does, there is pretty much nothing to convert because Rec709 is equal to sRGB in everything except gamma. And in case of gamma many players may just need the right tag.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff Zscale allows you to convert bt.709 EOTF of 2.4 gamma to correct gamma of sRGB with linear part. But yeah ideally just tag and wait for all players to support both EOTFs.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников I guess pure tagging could be treacherous because some tools like Handbrake may strip tags and so afterwards there’s gamma shift… again.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I was able to use ffmpeg with zscale where colour space conversion was _actually_ required (a single JPEG from Rec2020 to sRGB), this command seemed to work: `ffmpeg -i "$INFILE" -vf "zscale=transferin=2020_10:transfer=iec61966-2-1:primariesin=2020:primaries=709:w=0:h=0" -q:v 1 "$OUTFILE"` (it could probably simplified). I didn’t check colour reproduction too closely but there were no glaring artefacts or obvious gamma shift. Thanks to @ВалерийЗаподовников for the pointer

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff Sure, this is correct command, note that 2020_10 is just bt709 transfer. They are the same, even if 10 bit is supposed to be more accurate numbers, ffmpeg just uses ideal numbers in all cases. Do not forget to tag the output with -color_primaries and -color_trc.

Answer (score 1):

Your docs refer to the colorspace filter (which is the correct choice) but your attempts use other filters.

The colorspace filter only supports input depths of 8, 10 or 12 bits per channel, so ffmpeg will use its normal scaler to downsample the depth to 8 bpc beforehand. Let's delay that by manually downsampling to a higher depth.

```
ffmpeg -start_number 1001 -i input_seq_rec709.%04d.tif -vf format=yuv444p12le,colorspace=all=bt709:trc=srgb:format=yuv422p output_seq_srgb.%04d.jpg
```

The command above assumes that the input (TIFFs) have their color flags all set (and set correctly). If not, and colorspace complains, use

```
ffmpeg -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 -start_number 1001 -i input_seq_rec709.%04d.tif -vf format=yuv444p12le,colorspace=all=bt709:trc=srgb:format=yuv422p output_seq_srgb.%04d.jpg
```

Now, all of this is academic if the decoder of the player or onward app you use doesn't know to apply the correct gamma function.